# ctrl-c unsets echo on terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, signals

On different Linux distributions I experienced that pressing ctrl-c to stop a program (like 'cmp') or completion causes the terminal (usually xterm or gnome-terminal) to not echo the input any more. Blindly typing 'reset' fixes the terminal again. Does anyone else experiences this or even better knows how to fix it? I find it hard to reproduce and I am certain that some years ago it worked reliable.

Comment: I wouldn't expect killing `cmp` to have that effect. I can see it happening if you're running something that disables echo itself and doesn't handle `SIGINT` properly.

Comment: There've been several complaints about python command-interpreters (enough to make a nice entry in an FAQ someplace).

Comment: @KeithThompson, exactly. That it happens with programs like 'cmp' is what really surprises me.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that it's a consequence of your shell configuration. What shell are you using? Post its configuration files. Can you reproduce this in `bash --norc` or `zsh -f` or `ksh`?

Comment: @Gilles, I use bash (I had added the bash flag to indicate that but it was removed). Using it in the default configuration for a long time is sadly not really an option for me.

Comment: Well, you need to tell us how to reproduce the problem. Obviously other people don't experience this, otherwise it would be a well-known bug. So either tell us how to reproduce the problem with `bash --norc`, or post your whole configuration. Also be clear about when this happens: at first you state that it happens every time you press Ctrl+C, then you state that it's hard to reproduce. Which is it? If it doesn't happen all the time, what's special about the times when it does happen?

Comment: @Gilles, I think there is a misunderstanding. It doesn't happen every, but it is actually hard to reproduce the bug. And I have seen it happen with debian, rhel and archlinux.

Comment: wow, thanks for the `reset` hint! it saved my day

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs because some programs do not cleanup properly when they are interrupted.  The usual fix would be to use `reset` (you'll get less satisfactory results using `stty sane`):

reset<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

sends a newline even when your settings are messed up.

Further reading:

- [tset, reset - terminal initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html#h3-reset---reinitialization)